# Dropdown List Populated from Mysql with Multiple Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drop down list with the following code

```
$result = $conn->query("select province, town FROM areas");
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='town'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($province, $town);
    $province = $row['province'];
    $town = $row['town']; 
    echo '<option value="'.$town.'">'.$town.'</option>';
}

echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

My table Structure has two fields I need to record from the form, Town and Province. I have create the value town as shown in the above, What I would like to do is have two Values that my code will upload to the DB

On my second PHP file I $_POST the information as follow.

```
$town = $_POST['town'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
```

How can I capture multiple values using the dropdown

I have altered the code as follow:

```
$result = $conn->query("select province, town FROM areas");
                                    echo "<html>";
                                    echo "<body>";
                                    echo "<select name='prov_town'>";

                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                                  unset($province, $town);
                                                  $province = $row['province'];
                                                  $town = $row['town']; 
                                                  echo '<option value="'.$town.'_'.$province.'">'.$town.'</option>'; // I had extra "" in here that was not to be used

                                }

                                    echo "</select>";
                                    echo "</body>";
                                    echo "</html>";
```

Action Side:

```
$prov_town = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prov_town');
$parts = explode('_', $prov_town);
$town = $parts[0]; 
$province = $parts[1];
```

It inserts the Town but the Province is not being inserted I get this error

Undefined offset: 1 in

The error was in the Value section of my code extra "" added where not needed see notes above

Comment: Use 2 select tags

Comment: That will not be practical as I am drawing the information from one DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass two different properties from one select-input field.

You either need to have two different selects. One for Province, and one for Town. Or you could string the two together, with a delimiter and explode the values on the script that handles the POST parameters.

**Ex 1:**

```
<select name="province">
    <option value="detroit">Detroit</option>
</select>
<select name="town">
    <option value="new york">New York</option>
</select>
```

**Ex 2:**

```
<select name="province_and_town">
    <option value="provincename_townname">Province - Town</option>
</select>

$province_and_town = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'province_and_town');
$parts = explode('_', $province_and_town);
$province = $parts[0]; 
$town = $parts[1];
```

In the above example, its expected that province and town are separated by _. You then explode the input string on that delimiter, and get an array of the two values. This is not a perfectly written code, and will potentially fail if any of the values contains _, or if one of the values are missing, but it should give you an idea to a solution.

**EDIT:**

There is no problem using the results from a single query to populate data into multiple selects. Example:

```
$result = $conn->query("select province, town FROM areas");
$areas = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(!empty($areas)){
    echo "<select name=\"town\">";
        foreach( $areas AS $area ){
            echo "<option value=\"{$area['town']}\">{$area['town']}</option>";
        }           
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<select name=\"province\">";
        foreach( $areas AS $area ){
            echo "<option value=\"{$area['province']}\">{$area['province']}</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: While I admire the fact that you put effort in responding with a large answer, reading his answer to my comment shows that the OP has no idea what he's doing at all. He wants 2 values (like your Ex 1.) but doesn't understand that he can do that with 1 query, perhaps you can show him how to create 2 select boxes with that query, if you feel like it lol

Comment: Haha, well thanks Boratzan :P Updated. If this doesn't point in the right direction, Im buying him a compass

Comment: Using the edited section I get two dropdowns to select from Now I understand that part of two dropdowns but the Town needs to link with the Province in the edited version I have to select the town and then what province it is in over 5000 towns no idea what province they would be in as that is populated from the DB, The explode section will be more viable for me as it will populate the town and province with lets say lats longs as well

Comment: Ex2 is what I needed I needed to explode the string to get it into the DB Thanks